# Analog clock using CALayers

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer

I'm trying to make an analog clock for the iPhone, in which the clock hands will automatically update to the current time.  I also want the clock hands to be images, unlike this:  http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/03/analog-clock-using-quartz-core.html.  What would be the easiest way to create this using CALayers to rotate the images/hands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two properties of CALayers that may be of interest to you - the `anchorPoint` and the `transform`. Set the anchor point at the origin around which you want to rotate the images, calculate the angle of rotation, make a transformation matrix from it (using `CATransform3DMakeRotation` around the appropriate axis) and set the transform on the layer.

[It's all explained in detail here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW1).

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I'm completely new to CALayers.  The reference guide was helpful, but not enough... Do you have any sort of source or example?